# How to make image buttons in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

This doesn't display an image, but still works as a button.

```
<button><img src={"./img/google.png"} /></button>
```

My folder setup is /user/img/google.png and /user/loginGoogle.jsx , so I don't think there is a problem with source

Comment: Try `import MyImage from "./img/google.png"` and then write `<button><img src={MyImage} /></button>`.

Answer (score 23):

This will work:

```
<button><img src="./img/google.png" alt="my image" onClick={this.myfunction} /></button>
```

then if you define:

```
  myfunction() {
        console.log("CLICKED");
  }
```

and if you click your image you will see CLICKED appearing in the console.

So if you add the onClick listener to your image it will work. Then you can wrap that image in a button and even add some CSS class to it to match your needs.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hnCVFSBs

This is what I got now, onSubmit is defined above this, but I still don't get why I don't see the image @Theo

Comment: the code seems fine. It definitely works for me. Maybe the image url is wrong? What happens if you try this? http://soulsnatcher.bplaced.net/LDRYh.jpg

Comment: I just figured it out, it was kind of stupid, images must be in a public folder, I moved them there and now it works, thanks tho

Comment: <button><img src="/img/google.png" alt="my image" onClick={this.myfunction} /></button>

in my case this is working no need '.' in front of the '/img'

Answer (score 1):

If you're using React bootstrap button, typescript code work as below.

```js
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

<Button style={{backgroundImage:"url('./images/logo.png')",backgroundSize:"cover", width:"40px", height:"40px"}}></Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an 'img' as a button, it has an onClick property. It will also be easier to set hover effects and to do general styling that way.

`<img src={<url>} alt=<alt-string> width=<width> height=<height> onClick={() => <onClick function>}/>`

Answer (score 0):

Moved all the images to a public folder in my project and now it works

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src={require('/images/myImage.png')} />
```

make sure to change the file directory and name to your specific file.

Answer (score -2):

import logo from './logo.png'; // Tell webpack this JS file uses this image

// Import result is the URL of your image
return ;